# Model explodes with Displace

Tags: modifiers, uv, displacement, blend-files, 3d-printing

Solution: My strength was too high. Past problem was my faces were facing the wrong way. So if you have this issue check your faces and strength!

I am working on cleaning up a model for 3D printing, the only problem is, whenever I try to displace the texture over, the model explodes. I swapped all the faces, so they ~Should~ be facing the right way. This is my first time ever working with 3D models, so please explain things in laymen terms! (I need to do this with the outfit as well)

I attached the blender file in the link below
[image]

[image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/c936408c12064073b1b8bacc7e72ac3e

Using this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAau746Mdu8

Comment: Try reducing the strength of the Displace modifier

Comment: that worked thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The displace modifier will use the color values from the textures to "displace" the vertices of your mesh by default, your vertices will be moved along their normals :

[image]

You can think of the pixels any grayscale image as a number ranging from 0 to 1, where 0 represents pure black and 1 represents pure white. Blender will use those values to displace your mesh by mapping those values to [-1, 1].

Blender allows you to choose the strength of the displacement with the `Strength` parameter.

[image]

In your case, you just set the strength too high. Try to set it to a lower value like `0.1` or even lower according to the result you want to achieve.

You can find a full documentation about the displace modifier here :
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html

Comment: Thank you so much that worked!

Comment: I'm glad I helped. May I ask you to accept the answer so this topic can be marked as solved?